# Multiple objects moving in turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
while True:
    setupSeats()
    createPassenger()
    for passenger in passengers:
        passenger.speed(passengerspeed)
    for i in range(len(seats)):
        x = seats[i].pos()[0]
        y = seats[i].pos()[1]
        passengers[i].setx(x)
        passengers[i].sety(y)
        if i>1:
            passengers[i+1].setx(x-100)
```

This is for a plane simulation, passengers are red gif objects initiliazed at -900, 100. The issue is I can get  them moving one by one to their seat, but how would I get it to so that the passenger behind follows the current passenger and they all update.

Answer (score 0):

The Python `turtle` module doesn't allows you to have multiple things moving simultaneously, but you could have them each move in turn after the first one.

Comment: [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QC-M8tI9I30

Comment: That link shows a tutorial of it occuring